# Can't get my Update to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using a stored procedure to update the rows in the column where the consignment number = @consignmentnumber.

Here is a screen of the code.
I think I'm missing something but I can't work out I'm actually missing, can anyone help?

```
protected void BtnReceived_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IncrementStatusOfConsignment(sender);
}

private static void IncrementStatusOfConsignment(object sender)
{
    var button = (Button) sender;
    var gridviewrow = (GridViewRow) button.Parent.Parent;
    var consignmentnumber = gridviewrow.Cells[3].Text;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Test", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var sqlparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@consignmentnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlparam.Value = consignmentnumber;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong or what I'm missing?

I constantly get this error:
[image: error]

If I set the param to Int it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your `consignmentnumber` defined as a character in your stored procedure? Smells like you defined as an integer type in your sp..

Comment: i am unable to view the image in the link provided. what is the error you are getting can you paste in in the question.

Comment: As soner has already said said looks like you have the wrong type on your parameter, what is the value of `consignmentnumber` shoud you not convert this to an int?. Also what are you updating? I cannot see any value being passed into the SP.

Comment: try `SqlDbType.Decimal` instead `SqlDbType.VarChar`.

Comment: What datatype is `@consignmentnumber` in the stored proc?

Comment: @dasariramacharanprasad I've edited the question to include the embedded image, OP had included the web link not the source image URL.

Comment: Thank's @Soner_Gonur, It turnt out I had it wrong on the proc :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have declared column `consignmentnumber` as Numeric(18, 0) then

```
var sqlparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@consignmentnumber", SqlDbType.Decimal);
sqlparam.Value = consignmentnumber;
```

**OR** something like that:

```
var sqlparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@consignmentnumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 18);
sqlparam.Value = consignmentnumber;
```

Comment: Thanks all. But @Soner_Gonur, It turned out I had it wrong on the proc :D Thanks –